# Animating UIView size jumps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, caanimation

Tyring to animate a UIView by changing its height and position. The first animation jumps?  I have the size of the UIView (theView) set in Storyboards to be height of 216.  So the app loads and the theView is shown. I click theView and it quickly jumps in height to 200+ pixels then animates as it should?

```
- (void)singleTapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)singleTap {
UIView *view = singleTap.view;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    CGRect theFrame = self.theView.frame;
    theFrame.size.height += 100.f;  <!-- when it hits here the view jumps then animates
    self.theView.frame = theFrame;
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if(finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
                             CGRect theFrame = self.theView.frame;
                             theFrame.origin.y -= 100.f;
                             self.theView.frame = theFrame;
                         }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                              NSLog(@"animations complete");
                                          }];
                     }
                 }];
```

}

Comment: Not sure to understand your question. Just not, btw, that you have an "auto reverse" option in the UIView::animate .

Comment: @Vinzius you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving lines

```
CGRect theFrame = self.theView.frame;
theFrame.size.height += 100.f;  <!-- when it hits here the view jumps then animates
```

outside the block. Put it before the animation method is called.

Comment: Bounds will make it grow both directions because its not relative to its parent.

Comment: Vinzius above has the correct answer the issue was UIViewAnimationCurveLinear. If you change to UIViewAnimationCurveOut it works, but UIViewAnimationCurveLinear or UIViewAnimationCurveIn makes it jump. Or you can remove the options altogether and it works.